# font-family changes on using special characters through javaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make a weather app using OpenWeatherMap api. Apparently,i am trying to update my element's text through javaScript with a temperature and a '℃' symbol. The problem is that the '℃' symbol is not using the font-family mentioned in the corresponding css whereas the temperature value is all fine.
I have tried it this way-

```
$("#temp").text(data.temp+String.fromCharCode(8451));
```

Also,i tried this-

```
$("#temp").text(data.temp+String.fromCharCode(8451)).replace('font-family','Aclonica');
```

I searched for similar SO questions and googled for solution but got nothing.
Any kind of help would be appreciated. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most fonts only cover a certain range out of all possible (unicode) characters. Your font rendering engine will use the provided font if possible and use a fallback font to render characters for which the given font doesn't provide an icon / glyph.

This might explain your observation.

**Solution:** use a font with more glyphs / glyphs for all characters / code points you want to use - or add another (fallback-)font to your `font-family` which covers the missing characters. See also [Fallback fonts on special characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11395584/fallback-fonts-on-special-characters)

Comment: i have used another font to my font-family and it puts all the texts in a single font but not the one(fallback-) font i used.

Comment: btw thanks for the answer and how could i find out if some font has more glyphs or not? my code's at- http://codepen.io/srishti-learner/pen/aZBxZL ( in any case you want to check out).

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11395584/fallback-fonts-on-special-characters for the order of fallback fonts. Usually any font viewer would tell you the number of glyphs in a font. Most online font providers also list the glyphs of their webfonts.