# Apply font-type to specific html symbol entity (&trade;)

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am using a wordpress theme that has a font-type selection for page titles and content body. 
I'm using Montserrat for titles and Open-Sans for body.

I've got a few product titles where I need to input the trademark symbol ™ / `&trade;`

But the trademark symbol in the titles is coming up as a totally different font that looks like Times New Roman.

Is there a way to apply font-type only to the `&trade;` trademark html symbol entity? Globally?

I tried to use `<sub>TM</sub>` in titles which sort of works, it doesn't work everywehere, for example it wouldn't work in breadcrumbs.

Comment: No, you can not use CSS on parts of text (apart from special exceptions, such as f.e. `:first-letter`). You _need_ to have it wrapped in its own HTML element, if you want to be able to apply CSS formatting to it.

Comment: Montserrat does not have a glyph for ™, so the browser _has to_ use a different font that does to render it. https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Montserrat If you have another webfont that you would like the character to be displayed in, without having to manipulate the HTML, then you should go for a solution such as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11395584/fallback-fonts-on-special-characters, and add a font that contains that glyph to your font stack.

Comment: I see, that answers the question I guess, thanks ..

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can... but it's not really convenient:

`@font-face` rules have an [`unicode-range`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%40font-face/unicode-range) property that you could set to target a single character:

```js
c.onchange = e=> document.body.classList.toggle('amp');
```

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Ampersand';
  src: local('Courier');
  unicode-range: U+26;
}

body.amp{
  font-family: Ampersand, cursive;
  }
body{
  font-family: cursive;
  }
```

```html
<span>lorem ipsum dolor sit amer &amp; some others</span>
<input type="checkbox" id="c">
```

But as I said, it's not really convenient, since you have to make it the first font of all your font-family declarations where you want it to apply...

Comment: For completeness's sake, you can also subset the font file *itself* to a single character – which is the on-disk equivalent to using `unicode-range`.

Answer (score 0):

Typically one would use different markup for these and then use CSS to generate the content. For example, instead of

```
MyCompany&trade;
```

you might use

```
MyCompany<i class="symbol symbol-tm" />
```

And then use CSS

```
i.symbol {
    position: relative;
    width: 1.5em;
}

i.symbol.symbol-tm:after {
    display: inline;
    content: "\2122";
    font-family: "Times New Roman";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use the styledComponents library a fair bit and so in my usecase I wanted to create a global styled component which I could insert anywhere throughout my code which led me to the below solution:

```
export const Trademark = styled.span`
    ::before {
        display: inline;
        content: "\u2122";
        /* font-family: [your font family here] */
    }
`;
```

Which means I can call it anywhere using `<Trademark />`