# Different unicode versions on various devices

Tags: javascript, html, css, unicode, bitcoin

I created a Bitcoin Profit Calculator (whatifyouboughtbitcoin.com) and I would like to use  the "bitcoin symbol" as a character. The official symbol was accepted to Unicode in 2015 and first appeared in Unicode 10.0 which was released this year.

Currently I'm using Ƀ b/c it has been part of Unicode for a long time. I would like to switch to the new and official symbol ₿. The Problem is that only up to date Windows 10 and Android O support it currently. Which means most of the people will just see the missing-character-placeholder.

The question now is:

**Can I somehow (HTML/CSS or Javascript) show the new symbol on every device which supports it, while simultaneously showing something else on the rest?**

Thanks in advance. I will leave you with some background info you might find interesting: https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Bitcoin_symbol

Comment: You can use a web font that has the character.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fallback fonts on special characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11395584)

Comment: Just note - I see the `₿` correctly in macOS X too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this is not possible since you can not detect if the OS knows the character or not from a standard browser.

Possible workarounds are svg paths/images or as @SLaks suggested: a web font with a similar looking character.

If you are looking for a fallback `font-family` please check out [Fallback fonts on special characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11395584/fallback-fonts-on-special-characters)