# webfonts html substitute font not character

Tags: html, css, webfonts

I'm using a webfont that is missing certain characters.
Instead of using the characters from the next specified font that has those characters included it's substituting the character. Is there a way to force a font to use another font if it's missing a character rather than the character?.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11395584/fallback-fonts-on-special-characters